# Create multiple table inside store procedure in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have to create multiple table inside store procedure

```
create or replace procedure test()
language sql 
as $$
  drop table if exists a1;
  create table a1 as
  select * from mastertable;
  
   drop table if exists a2;
  create table a2 as
  select * from a1 with some filter
  
   drop table if exists a3;
  create table a3 as
  select * from a2 with some filter
;$$
```

But it threw an error

```
ERROR:  relation mastertable" does not exist
LINE 40:       from mastertable
```

Please help me fix it.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in first select, it says that masterable relation does not exist. You want to either create table masterable in public schema to be able to invoke it like this, or you should add **schema.** in front of table name(masterable). This should solve the issue, but also you are missing a couple of semicolons after filtering when creating table a2 and a3.

Comment: Mastertable mean the table which already existed, ..when we run it without procedure it execute but there is problem while using procedure  and i must create procedure for some reason

Comment: Well, the error you are having is that the procedure cannot see the table. That means that table does not exists, it is probably because of the search path or your scope of schemas that you see. Try creating the table first. Mybe you are dropping the mastertable somewhere and it is not seen in procedure.